# ruby class and method are not working

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am new in ruby and was trying to write a method to see the result this is my code

```
class Dog
  def speak
  puts "woof-woof"
end
harry= Dog.new()
harry.speak
```

Result:
woof-woof 
pink 
why does the result give me pink and not woof-woof please help

Comment: _pink_? What do you mean by _pink_?

Comment: Paste the exact output, please.

Comment: I am confused as well I don't know why the result is pink. that my i posted this question

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Why is there *no* `end` to your class `Dog`?

Comment: @Jagdeep Going by indentation, I'd say there is no `end` to his `speak` method :P.

Comment: Yeah, but `ruby` will not consider indentation while running this code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `end` for your `def`. Your code should be:

```
class Dog
  def speak
    puts "woof-woof"
  end
end
harry = Dog.new
harry.speak
```

Comment: I assumed their error messages were being displayed in pink / red. I figured it was just a language barrier thing.

Comment: thanks, @Nossidge that worked. is there any way I change speak output? like this:  harry.speak("hello I can talk too")

Comment: Sure: `def speak(noise); puts noise; end`. This is very basic stuff though, you should probably get started with a beginners Ruby tutorial. There's loads online if you search.